# Canopy fails to start if environment variable HTTP_PROXY is set to invalid value

Tags: python, canopy

canopy fails to start if environment variable HTTP_PROXY is set to invalid value.
how to set HTTP_PROXY for canopy from canopy command prompt?

Best Regards

Comment: Are you sure that Canopy won't even start? Or do you mean that you can't log in or use the package manager? Which Canopy version are you using? Proxy handling is much improved in the current 1.6.1. Are you asking about how to set an environment variable, or about the correct format of HTTP_PROXY?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm sure that Canopy won't even start. I use canopy-1.6.1-full-win-64. I already open canopy and set proxy in it but i forgot to clear proxy and then I closed the canopy. now I want to open canopy but canopy fails to start.

Comment: Ok, so it's almost certainly not your proxy setting which is causing the startup failure. First, try a full reset (not reinstall!) as described at https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy. If that doesn't work, send an email to support@enthought.com

Comment: thanks a lot. but based on [link](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B), my canopy fails to start, too.

Comment: Did you send the requested email?

Comment: Yes, and fortunately they answered to me. but I have not received an answer yet.    thank you again.

Comment: The answer that I have so far is. by use following command it will solve:              `del %appdata%\Enthought\Canopy\preferences.ini`    and also i installed canopy 1.6 without uninstall canopy 1.5.  they would suggest a complete uninstall of canopy 1.5 as described here:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Comment: Yes, I've seen your conversation with my colleague. Again, the problem almost certainly has nothing to do with your proxy setting, but with a messed up multiple installation. Please do as he suggests, please do a complete uninstallation, *including a reset which deletes all the other directories* and reinstall clean.

Comment: thank you very much. I uninstalled canopy 1.5 completely  and then installed canopy 1.6. it's work correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: the problem had nothing to do with proxy settings. The installation was corrupted. A complete uninstall and reinstall (as it happens of a more recent version) was successful.